# How to make search bar with filter that doesn't shift based on filter length

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigationbar

I want **to make a search bar like the one Amazon has, but** right now, **whenever I select a filter, it will shift the entire bar to the right**.

I am using **MaterialUI** to do this.

Ex: Selecting "All" as filter then selecting "clothes" as filter will shift everything to the right since the "all" is smaller than "clothes". I want to display the whole string and not hide it.

Right now my code looks a bit like this:

```
<Grid item>
<filter/>
</Grid>
<Grid item md={9}>
<searchbar/>
</Grid>
<Grid item>
<submit/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does setting the column width of the other 2 items help? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vgpd3

Comment: It does, but the thing is I want it the filter box size to be responsive based on the string length. It does this currently, but it shifts the entire search bar due to the size as a result. If you look at Amazon's search bar, it changes the box size while keep the search bar fixed in place.

Comment: Then make the responsive filter box a child of the set-width Grid Item.